# Wordpress rewrite strip trailing slash from images

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've had to move a WP site from a windows server to a linux one.
Wp is installed into a subfolder (blog) and an entire site was buildt "around" it (calling wp-header and retrieving contents). I've not made this one and was only providing some info in case it could be important... anyway, after the move all images are now unreachable ad gives a broken link both front and backend, that's because the link is always rewritten without a slash.
I.E.:

```
http://knindustrie.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/ABCT-B.jpg
http://knindustrie.comblog/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/ABCT-B.jpg
```

note the slash missing between .com and blog
I've tried with standard WP .htaccess and at the moment I've a blank one both on root and on the subdir and still the problem persists...

Any idea? 
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've somawhat solved this.
Looks like il was stripping the slash because the link was written without www.
I've done a search and replace on the db, replacing all occurrency of "http:\domainname.xx" with "http:\www.domainname.xx".
This one solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Check your permalink settings. If your permalink setting is `/%postname%`, then change this to `/%postname%/`

Shown here

[image]

This will effectively force the trailing slash.

Comment: It's like that already, and if I try to open a post, it works, only it won't load images. The links written into the page is correct, but the GET request is sent without the slash...

Comment: How are the images displayed? Ie have you manually added the links or have you added media from the gallery. If the gallery, please add another image and see if it also breaks. Let me know

Answer (score -1):

Just out of interest, do you have an issue in all browsers?
I am assuming that you have mod_rewrite enabled on your server?

Comment: All browsers and mod_rewrite is enabled... in fact if I try to open a post, it's working fine... only problem is with images